# Nested routes causing double rendering of a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component (Journeymen) rendering twice in my app. As far as I have been able to follow the logic of my app, everything seems to be OK, but from my readings I have come to understand that the issue can be related to my React Router configuration. In my src/App.js file, I have routes nested within routes, which, as I understand it, this can sometimes lead to unexpected rendering behavior.

I am trying to simplify out the configuration of my App.js file so that there are not as many nested routes, while preserving the distinction between routes that are `WithoutSidebar` and those that are `WithSidebar` and also `Protected`. I cannot see how to change this around. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the configuration of my App.js (skipping the import and export statements, which I believe irrelevant to the issue):

```
function App() {
  const { authChecked, loggedIn } = useAuth();

  return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<WithoutSidebar />}>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login loggedIn={loggedIn} />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<WithSidebar />}>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes isAllowed={loggedIn} authChecked={authChecked} redirectPath="/login" />}>
              <Route path="/" element={<Journeymen />} />
              <Route path="/journeymen/:id" element={<Journeyman />} />
              <Route path="/create-journeyman" element={<CreateJourneyman />} />
              <Route path="/delete-journeyman" element={<DeleteJourneyman />} />
              <Route path="/create-reservation/:id" element={<CreateReservation />} />
              <Route path="/reservations" element={<Reservations />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
};
```